# FInd remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^6-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find remainder when $f(x) = x^{219} - x^{180} + x^{90} + x^{48} + x^{11} - x^3$ is divided by $x^6-1$.

I know remainder theorem but here $x^6-1=0$ gives $x=1$ and I am not sure that putting $x=1$ in $f(x)$ will give required remainder. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Why don't you just divide and find it?

Comment: What's the remainder when $x^n$ is divided by $x^6-1$?

Comment: `not sure that putting x=1` How about putting $x^6=1$ instead. Then all powers reduce to exponents less than $6$.

Answer (score 2):

By Factor Theorem, $y^{36}-1$ is divisible by $y-1$. So

$$x^{216}-1=(x^6)^{36}-1$$

is divisible by $x^6-1$.

Also by Factor Theorem, $-y^{30}+y^{15}+y^{8}-y$  is divisible by $y-1$. So

$$-x^{180}+x^{90}+x^{48}-x^6=-(x^6)^{30}+(x^6)^{15}+(x^6)^{8}-(x^6)$$

is divisible by $x^6-1$.

\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^3(x^{216}-1)+(-x^{180}+x^{90}+x^{48}-x^6)+x^6(x^5+1)\\
&=x^3(x^{216}-1)+(-x^{180}+x^{90}+x^{48}-x^6)+(x^6-1)(x^5+1)+(x^5+1)\\
\end{align}

The remainder is $x^5+1$.